# (MicrosoftReport OR CrystalReport ) in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, microsoft-reporting

MicrosoftReport OR CrystalReport ?

Which is better?

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to steer away from CrystalReports.  But of course, you would need to determine whether any reporting solution meets your needs (which you do not state).

Comment: Can you please point to some reference as to why we should move away from CrystalReports? I am actually learning it, so need to have a second though now :)

Comment: It's a personal preference borne of experience!

Comment: have you looked at ActiveReports from http://www.datadynamics.com/ ?

Comment: Or DevExpress' XtraReports: http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/